# Create a function in a Google AppScript which stops another function

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a script in Google AppScript that does the monthly billing of employees. The problem is that the base is quite large, so when the employee responsible for settlements from a given branch chooses the wrong branch, he has to wait for the function to finish working. Hence my question, is it possible to create a button that cancels the execution of one function or the entire script? Alternatively, is there any function that catches that someone has pressed "cancel" in the popup banner while executing the script above the sheet?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There is native Lock service in Apps Script: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock

Comment: That could be useful but Im not sure how can I use it becouse I need to lock function from  pressed "cancel" in the popup banner or I need my custom cancel button. I have button whose start script and is disabled until the script finishes running but when someone use cancel on popup banner script stop working and my button become useless. It's become useless becouse when script is running I replace the functions in the button with another one. For example: I have function named Podmianka() assigned to button but when Podmianka is running I assigned function Alert() to this button.

Comment: Can you provide more details about this? Maybe add the relevant parts of the code and, in case it can be useful, a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a script runs google puts up a cancel button and a dismiss button.

Comment: Yeah I know, but when someone use this option my script become unusable becouse when script is running button whose is resposible for start script is disabled and when someone cancel operation button stay disabled.

Comment: You might be able to break out of a loop if you ran it from a sidebar but that would slow it down even more. It might be better to put a confirm on the original selection.

Comment: Hmm that could work like temporary solution but I'm not sure my boss will accept it ;/